# Can vertexes and edges in jGraphT be added parallely

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, jgrapht

I'm creating a graph in java using jGraphT and adding vertexes and edges from a list using a stream.

My question is:
Can I use `stream().parallel()` to add them faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at least not as far as I'm aware. Essentially, adding a vertex or edge boils down to 2 steps: (a) check whether the edge/vertex already exists and if not (b) add the edge/vertex. Depending on the type of graph, step (b) involves adding the object to the appropriate container that stores the edges/vertices. I'm not an expert on concurrent programming, but I don't see how a parallel stream can do the above faster.

I don't know exactly what your usecase is, or what you try to accomplish. There are however some optimized, special graph types in the jgrapht-opt package that might benefit you. The graph functionality doesn't change (i.e. you can run the same algorithms on them); only the way the graph is stored changes. Some storage mechanisms are more memory efficient, allowing you to store massive graphs using little memory. Other graphs, such as the sparse graphs, can be created quicker and access operations are also quicker, but these graphs are typically immutable, i.e. once created they cannot be changed. What you need really depends on your usecase.

Comment: My use case requires fast creation of large graphs. If concurrent execution is possible then multiple edges/vertexes can be created concurrently, resulting in a faster execution...